# Eloquent/Laravel: Calling function on relational object

Tags: eloquent

I'm trying to do the following:

The Page Object has one Route Object, which has a public function called getUrl().
Now I want to get the Url from a page:

$page->route->getUrl();

This returns the folowing error: "Call to a member function getUrl() on null"

However, when I call it inside the dd function, it works fine, also when I call the page's getUrl() function. These both work fine:

dd($page->route->getUrl());
$page->getUrl());

I thought that the route could not have been treated as a Route Object, but var_dump($page->route) returns a Route Object.

Can anyone explain that behaviour to me?

Comment: Please post more of your code. Where is `$page` coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your post. It actually helped me to solve the problem:

Comment: I use a plugin (laravel scout) to load the object from an external search engine (algolia), where something is obviously broken/missing.

    $pages = Page::search('searchterm')->hydrate();

When I use the normal eloquent search it works fine:

    $pages=Page::all();

foreach ($pages as $page){echo $page->route->getUrl();}